# Is $C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\; :\; \max \{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n\}\leq 1\}$ convex or not?

Tags: convex-analysis

> Is $C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\; :\; \max \{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n\}\leq 1\}$ convex or not?

As it has been mentioned in book of optimization that every max function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. So, I think for it may not effect whether it is equal to any positive or negative number. But I want to make sure, if my thinking is correct or not.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is convex.

Suppose $\max(x) \le 1$ and $\max(y) \le 1$. That is each component of $x$ and $y$ is at most $1$.

The $i$-th component is $\lambda x_i + (1-\lambda ) y_i \le \lambda + (1-\lambda)=1  $

Remark: In fact, it can be viewed as intersection of $n$ halfspaces.